# The same code without the double variable

Tags: java

I am not a java programmer. I am converting a code to another language and I found this line in java...

```
for (int ii = 0, i = 0; i < n; i += 2, ii++) {
```

two variables inside a for... I have to convert that to a language that doesn't have that.

I have googled around found several explanations but it is not exactly clear to me if I have converted it correctly.

As far as I understand that, the previous code is equivalent to

```
int ii = 0
for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2) {
  // do stuff
  ii++
}
```

as I see the internal variable `i` is the one controlling the loop and `ii` is just incrementing.

Is that assumption and the code correct?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Or `ii = n/2;` and `for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2) {  // do stuff }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current loop:

```
for (int ii = 0, i = 0; i < n; i += 2, ii++) {
```

The actual loop counter which determines how many times the loop will execute is the single dummy variable `i`.  The `ii` variable can be extracted out, leaving us with:

```
int ii = 0;
for (int i=0; i < n; i += 2) {
    // do something
    ++ii; // move increment inside the loop
}
```

Comment: @Tim Why you have used `++ii` instead of `ii++`?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference here.  I had a C/C++ professor once who advocated using pre- versus post-increment whenever possible.  Old habits die hard; though it doesn't change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you use **for** the logic will be a little weird when the logic of 2 vars are in different places, you can use while:

```
int ii = 0, i = 0;
while(i < n) {
    // do stuff
    i += 2;
    ii++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i += 2){
    int ii = i / 2;
    //do stuff
}
```

This keeps the scope of ii the same as before in case you use the same name in a later part of your program.